# Write large fixed width dataset in local database using RSQLite with R

Tags: r, database, bigdata, rsqlite

I have a many Gb fixed width dataset which I would like to write to a local database using RSQLite, since I can not load it into RAM memory. Does anyone know how to do this?

The preferred packages are:

- DBI
- RSQLite
- odbc

Does dbWriteTable write large datasets in chuncks? And can dbWriteTable handle fixed width datasets?

Comment: One strategy would be to identify the total number of rows `N`, loop through chunks of your fixed width file by reading it with `readr::read_fwf` and iteratively saving it with `dbAppendTable`. In the first iteration of your loop you'd probably use `dbWriteTable` to create the database in the first place.

Comment: dear @cimentadaj, thanks a lot for your suggestion!
Your suggestion brought me to the idea to use the package LaF and chunked:
LaF::laf_open_fwf()
and the functions chunked::read_chunkwise() and write_chunkwise()